# Show that the collection $\mathcal{T} = \{X\setminus C:C\in \mathcal{C}\}$ is a topology on $X$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of subsets of the set $X$. Suppose that $\emptyset$ and $X$ are in $\mathcal{C}$, and that finite unions and arbitrary intersections of elements of $\mathcal{C}$ are in $\mathcal{C}$. Show that the collection
$$\mathcal{T} = \{X\setminus C:C\in \mathcal{C}\}$$
is a topology on $X$.

Proof:

(i) Since $\emptyset, X\in \mathcal{C}$ therefore $X-\emptyset=X\in \mathcal{T}$ and also $X-X=\emptyset \in \mathcal{T}$.

(ii) Let $\mathcal{C}=\{C_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in{I}}$ be an indexed collection of subsets of $X$ with the stated properties. By DeMorgan's law, we know
$$\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} (X-C_\alpha)=X-\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} C_\alpha,$$
and since the right-hand side belongs to $\mathcal{C}$ by assumption, we conclude that $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} (X-C_\alpha)\in \mathcal{T}$ by definition.

(iii) Similarly to (ii), the finite union of any sub-collection of elements of $\mathcal{C}$ is in $\mathcal{C}$ by assumption, so by DeMorgan's law we have,
$$\bigcap_{i=1}^n (X-C_i) = X- \bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i \in \mathcal{T},$$
by definition. Conclude that $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X$.

Is this correct?

Comment: For (ii), you should begin with sets $X-C_\alpha$, not $C_\alpha$.

Answer (score 1):

While the reasoning is correct, you should be more careful about how you summon the objects you work with. eg in point ii) :

> ii) Let $\{X \setminus C_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in{I}}$ be an indexed collection of **elements of $\mathcal{T}$**, where each $C_\alpha \in \mathcal{C}$. By DeMorgan's law we get $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} (X-C_\alpha)=X-\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} C_\alpha$. By assumption, $\bigcap_{\alpha\in I} C_\alpha \in \mathcal{C}$ hence $\bigcup_{\alpha\in I} (X-C_\alpha) \in \mathcal{T}$.